# Backbone.js PushState routes .htaccess only working as hash but nowhere else

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js, routes, pushstate, hashbang

I have a website domain.com for example.  I have backbone.js with pushstate and fallback and when I goto  domain.com/about it loads up the index.html page and pushstates to about.   everything is working.  but if i want to goto a directory with a page inside like: www.domain.com/bio/moreinfo  for example, it does not work and throws a invalid page.  if i do it in IE it works fine.  my htaccess file has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
# html5 pushstate (history) support: 
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

if i navigate directly to the page domain.com/bio/moreinfo it craps out (i think because my server wants to goto the bio directory?  or maybe I need to actually control the routes in backbone differently?  its just that it works on bangs so it has to be some weird push state directory thing where #bio/info is not the same to apache as /bio/info .  any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yesterday there was a guy with the same problem, except that his was working on everything *but* IE. Together you have one working Router, congratulations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469467/backbone-history-deep-urls-are-not-falling-backing-properly-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well using the answer in another suggested post, which was to do
    `<base href="/" />`
in the index.html file.  This actually made the sub directories in my pushState work! just it was suggested.. but then in return it broke my IE, but i fixed it by putting extra code in my INIT of backbone

```
 Backbone.history.start({ pushState: Modernizr.history, silent: true });
if(!Modernizr.history) {
    var rootLength = Backbone.history.options.root.length;
    var fragment = window.location.pathname.substr(rootLength);
    var search = window.location.search;
    Backbone.history.navigate('/#' + fragment + search, { trigger: true });
} else {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.getFragment())
}
```