# .htaccess configured for pushState support; page errors on multi-parameter URL

Tags: .htaccess, routes, pushstate

I am using the following configuration in my .htaccess file to enable support for HTML5 pushState navigation on a website:

```
# HTML5 pushstate support
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [L]
```

This works works great when the url of the website is something like:

```
www.example.com/foo
```

However, I begin to encounter errors when using a more complex URL such as:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar
```

I found [this StackOverflow posts which directly addresses my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483076/backbone-js-pushstate-routes-htaccess-only-working-as-hash-but-nowhere-else). The proposed solution does work, but, to me, it seems like the wrong way to fix the problem. The suggested solution is to provide a `<base>` tag for the given page, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <base href="/" />
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works because [according to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) the `<base>` tag corrects relative links.

Okay, fair enough, but that's what the .htaccess file should be doing for me already, right?

Is this something that can/should be configured at a server level rather than on a per-page basis? Or is it standard to use the `<base>` tag in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is actually a HTML source problem** that is being solved by using:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

When you have your current URL as:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

And include your css/js/image with a **relative path** such as:

```
<img src="images/header.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/site.css">
```

Then browser will resolve above relative URLs from current's URL to make them:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/images/header.jpg
http://www.example.com/foo/styles/site.css
```

thus causing 404 for your image and css paths above.

With `<base>` as defined above browser will **correctly** request above URLs as:

```
http://www.example.com/images/header.jpg
http://www.example.com/styles/site.css
```

Sure some rewrite rules can be rewritten to redirect every image/css/js to root path by identifying these resources using extensions but those will be patches at the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On


# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

</ifModule>
```