# Flask serves static file, but without images

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to serve static files from Flask, but said static file contains an image which is not showing up. Here is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file("somefile.html")  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And here is my html file "somefile.html" which is in the "static" sub-directory under the directory which holds the above code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div> this is some garbage text </div>
  <img id="ansvg" src="./ppnow.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

The graphic is sitting in the same "static" subdirectory as somefile.html.

If I drag the html file directly into the browser, no problem, I get the graphic, but if I run the flask server and point to localhost:5000 then the graphics doesn't show up (though the text does).

What's going on? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are serving the HTML page under the root URL, `/`. The browser will then load all relative URLs based of the root url.

Your image is thus going to be loaded as `/ppnow.svg`, not `/static/ppnow.sgv`.

You could fix the link to the image, or you could alter the base URL with a [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

```html
<base href="/static/">
```

Note that without a domain name (an absolute URL) the base tag may be ignored by IE.

Comment: Do even the latest versions of IE ignore the base tag if an absolute URL is not provided?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne: I try to avoid front-end issues. [IE doesn't support relative paths in the base element when referencing CSS files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6541721) suggests that IE 7, 8 and 9 do not support it, certainly. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535191(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't say newer versions do support relative URLs.